# T-SQL Raiserror Losses Message If Includes Datetime Converted To Char(10)

Tags: sql, string, datetime, raiserror

Okay, so I am trying to raise an error in T-SQL (SQL-2000).  The base Sql code looks like this . . .

```
declare @TmsString  char(10),
        @TmsLast    datetime,
        @UserMsg    varchar(500)

select @TmsLast = getdate()

select  @TmsString = ltrim(rtrim(convert(char(10), @TmsLast, 101)))
select  @UserMsg = '*' + ltrim(rtrim(cast(@TmsString as char))) + '*'

raiserror (@UserMsg, 12, 1)
return
```

My Managed C++ Code in VS2008 to catch the raiserror looks like this . . .

```
System::Void Sql_ExecuteQuery (SqlCommand ^ sqlCommand, DataSet ^ OutDS, String ^ TableName)
{
   SqlConnection   ^ sqlConnect ;
   SqlDataAdapter  ^ sqlDA ;

   try
   {
      sqlDA = gcnew SqlDataAdapter () ;

      sqlConnect = gcnew SqlConnection (_ConnString) ;
      sqlConnect->Open () ;

      sqlCommand->Connection = sqlConnect ;

      sqlDA->SelectCommand = sqlCommand ;
      sqlDA->Fill (OutDS, TableName) ;
   }
   catch (Exception ^ excp)
   {
      throw gcnew Exception (excp->Message->ToString()) ;
   }
   finally
   {
      sqlConnect->Close () ;
   }
}
```

Now, I have a breakpoint sest at the catch within the "C++" code.  If the raiserror message includes the datetime as a CHAR, the excp->Message is empty.  If I remove the datetime as a CHAR and just send a hardcoded raiserror message such as "Error happens here", then the excp->Message is complete and filled in with the raiserror message.

Has anybody else seen this type of activity?  What can I do on either side of this call . . . i.e., either on the SQL side or the C++ side to get this datetime string included in the raiserror message????

Please, help.  I am stuck!

THANK YOU !

Comment: Which result do you want to see?

Comment: Ultimately, the raiserror message needs to say . . . "Employee Id 12345 Last Logged on on 12.31.2010 8:33AM".  I am getting the value for @TmsLast from a query to the logon table.  Yes, I know that the @TmsLast has a valid date in it because if I return it in a result set, the value is filled in.  It isn't until I try to concatenate the datetime as a char to a raiserror message that the contents of @TmsLast gets "lost". . . . HELP !!!!

Answer (score 0):

What you are executing is

```
declare @UserMsg    varchar(500)
select  @UserMsg = '*' + convert(char(10), getdate(), 101) + '*'
raiserror (@UserMsg, 12, 1)
return
```

I guess you would like to concatinate a user msg somehow.

Comment: Ultimately, the raiserror message needs to say . . . "Employee Id 12345 Last Logged on on 12.31.2010 8:33AM".  I am getting the value for @TmsLast from a query to the logon table.  Yes, I know that the @TmsLast has a valid date in it because if I return it in a result set, the value is filled in.  It isn't until I try to concatenate the datetime as a char to a raiserror message that the contents of @TmsLast gets "lost". . . . HELP !!!!

Comment: I don't see any variable where you have the raiseerror message

Comment: Are you thinkung of  @TmsString, @TmsLast, @UserMsg as parameters they are not think of them as local Variables. And there is no place within your sql where you concatenate anything, besides the adding of the '*'.

Comment: hay! what was your fix?